# Passing parameters to dots that conflict with explicit parameters

Tags: r, r-caret

The `caret::train()` function has an explicit `method` parameter, for which we can specify the machine learning method to use (like `MASS::polr`).  Further, `caret::train()` allows you to pass parameters to the method function via the `...` (dots) parameter.

However, one of the `MASS::polr` parameters I'd like to pass is `method`, which conflicts with the `caret::train()` `method` parameter.

How does one specifically pass the `polr` `method="probit"` parameter to `polr` while still passing the `method="polr"` parameter to `caret::train()`?

Not sure if there is a specific trick for `caret::train()` or a general trick for function dots vs. named function parameters that clash in general.

Specifically, I need:

```
  ## Generic example, no data, but captures idea
fit <- train(xdata, ydata, method="polr" # this 'method' is named parameter for train() function
  , preProcess = c("center", "scale")
  , method="probit" # this 'method' parameter needs to be passed via dots to 'polr'
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the ... option passes the needed parameters to the underlying function. But in some cases this indeed clashes with the existing parameters in the train function. In case of `polr` this is solved via `tuneGrid`.

See [the available models](http://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html) page and search for polr.

In the formula notation it should look like this:

```
train(y ~ x1 + x2, 
      data = my_data, 
      method = "polr", 
      trControl = my_control, 
      tuneGrid = expand.grid(method = "probit"))
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great.  I went to the available models page and found `polr`, but it did not mention how to pass this parameter.  Also, I didn't think this was a tuning parameter, so didn't try passing via `tuneGrid`.  I think I'll file an issue and ask for an example to be explicitly given on passing this paramter. I checked their regression tests, and I didn't see an example of passing this parameter... https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/RegressionTests/Code/polr.R

Comment: Submitted as issue for explicit documentation here: https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/554